# status: Unknown job: smbd

Tags: ubuntu, vps, samba

I'm trying to set up a new VPS (Ubuntu 10.10 x64) and I'm wondering if this is going to be a problem:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
 * Reconfiguring network interfaces...                                 ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 1445
status: Unknown job: smbd
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 1474
status: Unknown job: smbd
                                                                     [ OK ]
```

There's an `/etc/init.d/smbd` but when I try to restart it I get the error in the title. I haven't done much so far; added a user, ran an `update` and an `upgrade`, an `update-rc.d -f apache2 remove`, and a `reboot`. `dpkg` says `samba` is installed.

I don't plan on using Samba but the crumbs it seems to have placed around the system are perplexing to me. Should I simply ignore this, as everything seems to be working fine, or is this a case of misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu uses Upstart.

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/

It looks like in this case that starting up networking starts up the other networking services, including Samba. Likely in this case that Samba is misconfigured, so it couldn't start up. You can either fix Samba or uninstall it if you are not using it.

Answer (score 0):

The error "status: Unknown job: smbd" can happen when upstart tries to connect to the user upstart session rather than the system upstart session and can't find the service it wanted. Try using `sudo -s` or `su -` to become root (which will clear the `UPSTART_SESSION` environment variable) before running further commands that directly/indrectly start services. The Ubuntu bug [Newly installed openssh-server and upstart: status: Unknown job: ssh](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1367214) has more details.